# add and remove class jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

my html look like this

```
<ul id="navigation">
 <li><a href="#">menu 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">menu 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">active me</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">menu 4</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="subNavigation">
 <li><a href="#">click me</a></a>
 <li><a href="#">click me</a></a>
 <li><a href="#">click me</a></a>
</ul>
```

I want to achieve is when click any of `#subNavigation` links, *active me* in `#navigation` always have `current-menu-item` `class`

I try this JS, but not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('#subNavigation > a').click(function () {
                  $('#navigation:nth-child(3)').addClass("current-menu-item");
              });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

css

```
.current-menu-item {color:#000}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method

```
$(function () {
    $('#subNavigation a').click(function () {
        $('#navigation li:eq(2)').addClass("current-menu-item");
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gSALD/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `li` on navigation.

```
$(function() {
    $('#subNavigation > a').click(function () {
              $('#navigation li:nth-child(3)').addClass("current-menu-item");
          });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code: `$('#navigation:nth-child(3)').addClass("current-menu-item");`

This: `'#navigation:nth-child(3)'`

select the third element with `navigation` id. Brcause [:nth-child() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) select the specific index of the child elements collection/set.

So, you should first select the child `li` and then select the specific number of child `li` (in your case you are trying to get third `li` element)  .

Use this:

```
$('#navigation li:nth-child(3)').addClass("current-menu-item");
```

Or if you want to select the `anchor tag`:

```
$('#navigation li:nth-child(3) > a').addClass("current-menu-item");
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6HpW/)

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SyZ9L/)**
 try using `eq()`

```
 $('#subNavigation li a').click(function () {
    $('#navigation li:eq(2)').addClass("current-menu-item");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jjs5F/

There are a few things wrong:

1. Remember to properly nest your lists under subNavigation.
2. You are trying to select the immediate anchors under subNavigation, not anchors in list items.

   ```
   $('#subNavigation > li > a')
   ```
3. You need to specifiy li when adding the class:

   ```
   $('#navigation li:nth-child(3)')
   ```